# Intermediate field of a simple field is finitely generated

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $K(a)$ simple algebraic extension of the field $K$ and $L$ intermediate field. Let $m(x)=a_0+a_1x+\ldots+a_mx^m\in L[x]$ the minimal polynomial of $a$ over the field $L$. Prove that $L=K(a_0,a_1,\ldots,a_m)$.

I know that $K(a_0,a_1,\ldots,a_m)\subseteq L$ is easy, because $L$ contains every $a_i$ and $K$. I do not have an idea for the other direction but any idea is welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $M=K(a_0,a_1,\ldots,a_m)$. We will try to prove that $L=M$. Notice that $K\subseteq M\subseteq L\subseteq K(a)$, and thus $M(a)=L(a)=K(a)$.

Now: $[K(a):L]=[L(a):L]=m$ as the degree of the minimal polynomial $m(x)\in L[x]$ is $m$.

On the other hand, $m(x)\in M[x]$ as all its coefficients are actually in $M$, so $[K(a):M]=[M(a):M]\le m$, the right side being the degree of *some* polynomial ($m(x)$) in $M[x]$ which vanishes at $a$, while the left side is the degree of the *minimal* polynomial.

We end up concluding $[K(a):L]=m\ge[K(a):M]=[K(a):L]\cdot[L:M]$, which implies (after cancelling $[K(a):L]$) that $[L:M]\le 1$, i.e. $[L:M]=1$, i.e. $L=M$.